# Unexpected ( on a empty line

Tags: javascript

### Problem

The following code compiles with following error:

- `Unexpected token ) path/file.js:3:296`

---

### Code

The following script represents a simple function taking two int arguments, and converting them in some way. I won't go into details as the problem is a syntax error. 
PS. I am aware this algorithm doesn't work yet, the problem is pure the error chrome is showing up.

```
function freeTimeCalculator (fuelPrimary, fuelSecondary) {
var freeTime, secondaryFuel, freeTimeFactor = 0.5, fuelSecondaryFactor = 0.3;

  function displayResults() {
    // Calculate variables
    calculateTime();

    // Display results
    console.log("Free time: " + freeTime);
    return console.log("Secondary fuel: " + secondaryFuel);
  }

  function calculateTime () {
    var hours = [], minutes = [];
        // Notice: both arrays and indexes getting tied up
        hours[0] = minutes[0] = fuelPrimary.toString();
        hours[1] = minutes[1] = fuelSecondary.toString();

    // Calculation on strings
    // Notice: we take advantage that a notation may contain
    // many hours even 100, but the minutes will be always
    // the last two numbers.
    hours[0] = parseInt(hours[0].substr(0, hours[0].length-2));
    minutes[0] = parseInt(hours[0].substr(hours[0].length-2, hours[0].length));
    hours[1] = parseInt(hours[1].substr(0, hours[1].length-2));
    minutes[1] = parseInt(hours[1].substr(hours[1].length-2, hours[1].length));

    // Assigning values to the global variables
    freeTime = ((hours[0] * 60 + minutes[0]) * freeTimeFactor);
    return secondaryFuel = ((hours[1]) * 60 + minutes[1]) * fuelSecondaryFactor);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You have an extra `}` in there

Comment: Count the number of parenthesis on the return line for `calculateTime`.

Comment: Why do you have `(hours[1])` anyways?

Comment: For future reference, you can use http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home to determine syntax errors and other goodies.

Comment: True, I got confused because of the error, thanks for help.

Comment: @Ian It's a mistake as the algorithm was edited, and this needs to be corrected. But anyways it's not a huge mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the last line:

```
return secondaryFuel = ((hours[1]) * 60 + minutes[1]) * fuelSecondaryFactor);
```

to

```
return secondaryFuel = ((hours[1]) * 60 + minutes[1]) * fuelSecondaryFactor;
//                                                                         ^
```

**EDIT:-**

Also the code has extra **`}`** brackets. Do remove them. To be precise one extra **`}`** bracket at the end

Comment: @showdev Not really.. It just isn't *nessesary*. `(2 + (3 + (4 + (5))))` is still the same as `2 + 3 + 4 + 5`.

Comment: @h2ooooooo It's been edited. There were 2 opening parenthesis and 4 closing. But Rahul fixed it already :)

Comment: Yes thanks, I was just surprised about the error Chrome displayed that's why I got confused, and posted this question. Sorry tho.

Answer (score 2):

You have a stray `)` on the last line. This -

```
return secondaryFuel = ((hours[1]) * 60 + minutes[1]) * fuelSecondaryFactor);
```

should be either this -

```
return secondaryFuel = (hours[1] * 60 + minutes[1]) * fuelSecondaryFactor;
```

or this -

```
return secondaryFuel = ((hours[1] * 60 + minutes[1]) * fuelSecondaryFactor);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have extra `)` here

```
return secondaryFuel = ((hours[1]) * 60 + minutes[1]) * fuelSecondaryFactor);
                                 ^
```